# create csv file from array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, export-to-csv

I have an Array of dictionary like this :

The dictionaries are created :

```
let dateOfSurvey = String(NSDate())
let idOfSurvey = General.codeClasse + "-" + String(General.codePersonnel)
let dictionaryResults = ["dateOfSurvey": dateOfSurvey,
                         "ID": idOfSurvey,
                         "themaQuestionStep": questionResultThema,
                         "actionQuestionStep": questionResultAction,
                         "F01D1a": questionResult01,
                         "F02D2c": questionResult02,
                         "F03D3a": questionResult03,
                         "F04D4a": questionResult04,
                         "F05D1b": questionResult05,
                         "F06D2b": questionResult06,
                         "F07D3b": questionResult07,
                         "F08D4b": questionResult08,
                         "F09D1c": questionResult09,
                         "F10D2a": questionResult10,
                         "F11D3c": questionResult11,
                         "F12D4c": questionResult12]
```

then added to an array :

```
        arrayOfResults.addObject(dictionaryResults)
```

I would like to send/export the result by mail and think a CSV file would be a good way.

Is there a simple way to create this csv from the array of dictionaries in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After no solution for array of dict I have to change the data in a list of arrays
*dictionaryResults* become *arrayOfSurvey*

```
let dateOfSurvey = String(NSDate())
let idOfSurvey = General.codeClasse + "-" + String(General.codePersonnel)
let arrayOfSurvey = [dateOfSurvey , idOfSurvey , questionResultThema , questionResultAction, questionResult01, questionResult02, questionResult03, questionResult04, questionResult05, questionResult06, questionResult07, questionResult08, questionResult09, questionResult10, questionResult11, questionResult12]
```

I lose the key-value but now be able to put the data in cvs

```
arrayOfResults.addObject(arrayOfSurvey)
let count = arrayOfResults.count
General.cvs = "dateOfSurvey" + "," + "ID" + "," + "themaQuestionStep" + "," + "actionQuestionStep" + "," + "F01D1a" + "," + "F02D2c" + "," + "F03D3a" + "," + "F04D4a" + "," + "F05D1b" + "," + "F06D2b" + "," + "F07D3b" + "," + "F08D4b" + "," + "F09D1c" + "," + "F10D2a" + "," + "F11D3c" + "," + "F12D4c"
for i in 0...count {
    let arrayAtIndex = arrayOfResults.objectAtIndex(i)
    let stringRepresentation = arrayAtIndex.componentsJoinedByString(",")
    General.cvs += "\n" + stringRepresentation
                }
let fileData = General.cvs.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```